# SWRevealViewController slide out does not work after performing an action

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

My initial slide-out works perfect but when i move to another view controller and perform an action my slide-out doesn't work.

thanx in advance.when

Comment: What kind of action ? you must post your code for better understanding.

Comment: action to call another view controller and when i return to previous vc my menu button  does not navigate to slide-out screen  instead to a plain tableview.

Comment: Can you please show your code where you call SWRevealViewController's slide out method ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, B Kavee! Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but you have to provide more details and some code. Please see “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`SWRevealViewController` has `revealToggle:` to open and close the menu. You can solve problem by setting `revealToggle` method in each `- (void)viewDidAppear:` method of every different `ViewController` those will be handled by side menu as `_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);`

Comment: i have added that too, now the problem is when i return back from second view controller my first view controller is not pushing back to slide-out instead it displays only the tableview content.